# Catch Floating Point Exceptions using a compiler option with C

Tags: c, floating-point, fortran, scientific-computing

**Gfortran** has the handy `-ffpe-trap` compiler option, but no similar option is available for **gcc**.  I am vaguely aware that they handle exceptions differently, but not enough to know why one can die from **FPEs** just by enabling a compiler flag, but the other requires including extra code to turn exceptions on.

Comment: Note in Fortran 2003 one can do a lot off stuff similar as in C with the IEEE exceptions and rounding modes. Not supported by gfortran yet though. If the compiler flag was used to trap the exception it would probably interfere with such a code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Sorry for the wall of text; the real answer is at the bottom.*

Floating point exceptions are controlled by library code in C99, not by compiler flags. Here's an example:

```
#include <fenv.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define PRINTEXC(ex, val) printf(#ex ": %s\n", (val & ex) ? "set" : "unset");

double foo(double a, double b) { return sin(a) / b; }

int main()
{
    int e;
    double x;

    feclearexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT);

    x = foo(1.2, 3.1);

    e = fetestexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT);
    PRINTEXC(FE_DIVBYZERO, e);
    PRINTEXC(FE_INEXACT, e);
    PRINTEXC(FE_INVALID, e);
    PRINTEXC(FE_OVERFLOW, e);
    PRINTEXC(FE_UNDERFLOW, e);

    putchar('\n');

    feclearexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT);

    x += foo(1.2, 0.0);

    e = fetestexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT);
    PRINTEXC(FE_DIVBYZERO, e);
    PRINTEXC(FE_INEXACT, e);
    PRINTEXC(FE_INVALID, e);
    PRINTEXC(FE_OVERFLOW, e);
    PRINTEXC(FE_UNDERFLOW, e);
    return lrint(x);
}
```

Output:

```
FE_DIVBYZERO: unset
FE_INEXACT: set
FE_INVALID: unset
FE_OVERFLOW: unset
FE_UNDERFLOW: unset

FE_DIVBYZERO: set
FE_INEXACT: set
FE_INVALID: unset
FE_OVERFLOW: unset
FE_UNDERFLOW: unset
```

---

Update: With GNU GCC, you may be able to alternatively cause floating point exceptions to trap and send a signal:

```
#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS on

#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <fenv.h>

int main()
{
#ifdef FE_NOMASK_ENV
    fesetenv(FE_NOMASK_ENV);
#endif

    // ...
}
```

However, it's not entirely clear what you should do when you receive a SIGFPE, since you can't undo the faulty instruction. (And see @EricPostpischil's comments about the pragma; thanks!)

Comment: I don't think that this answers the OP's question in any way. The OP is asking *why* gfortran has a flag for FPE and gcc does not, not *how* does one flag a FPE in C.

Comment: @KyleKanos: You're right. I wasn't entirely sure what I was looking for, but now I found it. Updated.

Comment: Code that accesses the floating-point environment or runs under non-default floating-point control modes must inform the implementation by using `#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS on`. Otherwise, the behavior is undefined by the C standard.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Thanks! Is that requirement itself part of the standard?

Comment: @KerrekSB: C 2011 (N1570) 7.6.1, and it was in C 1999 too. Actually, it is too strong to say the behavior is undefined if the pragma is missing. The default FENV_ACCESS state is implementation-defined. If the implementation defines it to be “off” and the pragma is missing, then behavior is undefined by the standard. If I recall correctly, GCC did not support the pragma for a while.

Comment: @KyleKanos said it better than I did:  _why_ do I need to use `feenableexcept` or `fsetenv` rather than just a compiler flag?

Comment: @bwkeller: Because the standard says so?

Comment: @KerrekSB Awesome, there's my answer.  Thanks so much!